# Trying to find a character ('@') in a DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a fairly large DataFrame with a lot of chemical formulas. I'm getting an error with the code I'm using saying there's an '@' symbol in one of the formulas. I need to search what row has the @ and remove the row in the DataFrame. I've tried using the Excel to find it but the file is too large. Below is how big the DataFrame is

```
            formula
411143      Na3MnAl
498544       ReW3Se
331271   Li2Bi2P2O9
524939  SiH20(C6F)6
473999      PmGdMn2
...             ...
570767      Ta4CrHg
13388         Al5Tl
3580       Ag2HgAs2
569934         Ta3P
132241      Cr3CoIr

[692958 rows x 1 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.contains`:

```
# Keep right rows (recommended)
df = df[~df['formula'].str.contains('@')]

# Or drop bad rows
df = df.drop(df[df['formula'].str.contains('@')].index)
```

Comment: When doing the second option my it says that there are NaNs or Nones in the column now instead of just True and False. I tried `df = df_screen['formula'].str.contains('@').dropna()` but it's saying that it's `dtype: object` not `bool`